# Sum by max order of specified column

Tags: python, pandas, influxdb

I would like to sum a column by order of max from another column. I mean there is a descending order column `created_at` on the right. I want to sum each `last` based on the descending order. So the `created_at` 57 and 106 would sum together. Then comes 56 and 105. Etc... Any help would be appreciated.

`ext_bal` dataframe sample:

```
            time             app_vendor_id      last     source currency  created_at
0  2019-06-23 00:00:00+00:00           PTE       0.0  COINCHECK      XRP          57
1  2019-06-22 00:00:00+00:00           PTE       0.0  COINCHECK      XRP          56
2  2019-06-21 00:00:00+00:00           PTE       0.0  COINCHECK      XRP          55
3  2019-06-20 00:00:00+00:00           PTE       0.0  COINCHECK      XRP          54
4  2019-06-19 00:00:00+00:00           PTE       0.0  COINCHECK      XRP          53
5  2019-06-18 00:00:00+00:00           PTE       0.0  COINCHECK      XRP          52
...
18 2019-08-19 00:00:00+00:00           PTE  570100.0   COINBASE      XRP         106
19 2019-08-18 00:00:00+00:00           PTE  570100.0   COINBASE      XRP         105
20 2019-08-08 00:00:00+00:00           PTE  570100.0   COINBASE      XRP         104
21 2019-08-07 00:00:00+00:00           PTE  570000.0   COINBASE      XRP         103
22 2019-08-06 00:00:00+00:00           PTE  570050.0   COINBASE      XRP         102
23 2019-08-05 00:00:00+00:00           PTE  570020.0   COINBASE      XRP         101
24 2019-08-04 00:00:00+00:00           PTE  570020.0   COINBASE      XRP         100
25 2019-08-03 00:00:00+00:00           PTE  570080.0   COINBASE      XRP          99
```

The desired output sample:

```
   app_vendor_id      last      currency  created_at
0            PTE      570100.0      XRP          0
1            PTE      570100.0      XRP          1
```

My code:

```
ext_bal = ext_bal.groupby(['app_vendor_id', 'created_at' ,'currency']).sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: I don't see that "created_at" column is in descending order? I feel that something is missing, What is the logic to combine 57 and 106. Maybe another factor should be taken into consideration. Can you show the result of your code?

Comment: Maybe I should add that the `created_at` column is descending with a break (reinitialization) when a new `source` is appearing. The entire dataframe include 57 rows with `COINCHECK` and 106 rows with `COINBASE`

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works:

```
df['created_at_mask'] = df.created_at.sub(df.created_at.shift()).fillna(df.created_at.iloc[0])

df.loc[df['created_at_mask']==-1.0, 'created_at_mask'] = np.nan

df['created_at_mask'] = df['created_at_mask'].ffill()

groups = dict(list(df.groupby(by='created_at_mask')['last']))

pd.concat([e.reset_index(drop=True) for e in groups.values()],1).sum(1)

0    570100.0
1    570100.0
2    570100.0
3    570000.0
4    570050.0
5    570020.0
6    570020.0
7    570080.0
dtype: float64
```